# Why is not my divul until the end?

Tags: html, css

I have this site:

[link](http://www.delumine.ch/)

The problem is is that after a certain resolution, my div is not until the end.

Look at the image below to see more clearly what the problem is.
White space appears on the right who do not know where it comes from and how to remove it

[image]

Can you please tell me where you think comes this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

1. You are specifying the width of the header/footer.
2. You have use absolute positioning for a few elements. Eg: the link "dg-design.ch"

Fix : Don't use absolute positioning(or use it carefully), in your case remove the width you have specified.

But I would suggest use [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) and rework on the page, since you may find many more issues in compatibility with different screen sizes.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you try this:

`body{
   margin:0;
   text-align:center;
}`